# Is the “grammatical-interpretation” tag needed?

Tags: discussion

Is the [grammatical-interpretation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-interpretation) tag needed, or can it be merged with [grammar](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)?

Comment: It has no questions, so it will be removed automatically after some time.